# Remote object call in ModuleLoader

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds

I am Using Module Loader and Remote Object.

code.

```
public function continueClick():void 
{
   loader1.url = "Module.swf";
}
<mx:Button label="Continue" clenter code hereick="continueClick();" />
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" width="100%" height="100%">
   <mx:ModuleLoader id="loader1" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

When i load the Module the Remote Object is calling the Java method.
at the 2nd time its not calling Java methods.
Whats the Problem?

Remote Object calls are using BlazeDS
i set to clear the URL by loader1.url="" and 
loader1.url = "Module.swf?nocache="+new Date().getTime()+""; but still issue not solved

Answer (score 0):

If you set loader1.url to same value twice, it will not reload the module.

Comment: Hi i set to clear the URL by loader1.url="" and 
loader1.url = "Module.swf?nocache="+new Date().getTime()+""; but still issue not solved

Comment: Ok, I see. In that case your module is reloaded. If I were you I would debug those remote objects connection and request logics - may be you have to close them before unloading module, or maybe you are using some static variables which are no cleared. And by the way, what if you try to load this module in two different loaders?

Comment: I guess that your modules use some resource that can't be used twice(share object name, for example. or connection on same port, or something like that). You can try to use some program like Charles or HTTPAnalyzer to see what requests are exactly sent and how server responds to them.